# Word to describe what an academic degree is "in"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

I am trying to describe the individual components of a a list of academic degrees:

> AS Accounting
>
> AS Marketing
>
> BA Sociology
>
> BA Economics
>
> BS Accounting/Finance
>
> BS Information Technology

The first 'word' is a two-letter code indicating the degree level (associate's, bachelor's, etc.).

Is there a word to describe the remaining content of the degree?  Normally, I hear this described as "An Associate's Degree in Accounting", or "my bachelor's in Sociology."  Other words I have considered but am unsure about include:

> Concentration
>
> Focus
>
> Specialization

I am looking for a word or phrase that could complete any or all of the following sentences:

> "The _____ of my associate's degree is Accounting"
>
> "The _____ of my bachelor's degree is Sociology"
>
> "The _____ of my master's degree is Education"

EDIT:
A bit more context for my request - I am constructing a database holding information about a university, and trying to name the field containing the second portion of the values listed above (Accounting, Marketing, etc.)

Comment: Most people would eschew the first three words. My _____'s degree is in _______.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Field of study](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor%27s_degree) is the generalized term for the subject of the degree given.

Answer (score 11):

I think 'subject' would work for all your examples.

Comment: Please give a rationale for your answer.

Comment: @MattЭллен If you put 'subject' into the OP's sentences, it works. What better rationale could there be than that?

Comment: +1 - This answer also would have satisfied the requirements of the question I posted, but "Field of Study" was chosen by our user base.

Answer (score 1):

I generally hear it called a ***major***.  Wikipedia says that's supposed to be for undergraduate degrees (Associate's, Bachelor's), but it should be well understood at any level.

Comment: ***major*** is a [US/Canadian term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_(academic)); moreover only applies to undergrad. ***Field of study*** is universally understood, and is generic.

Answer (score 1):

***"Field"*** would be my first choice, as in "field of study" — but "of study" is unnecessary in the context. The term is commonly-enough understood on its own that there's a [classic corny joke](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KLrh.jpg) about it.

Another option would be ***"discipline"*** (as in, "[academic discipline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_academic_disciplines)"). (No jokes for that one.)

Comment: +1 solely on the basis of your usage of the word "corny"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest *"scope"*, *"field"*  or maybe, frenchy-fancy, *"métier"*

Though "métier" would normally not be used in the context of an aimed study but more likely in narrative, respectively casual language. E.g.:

> After trying several careers, she found her true métier in computer science. (merriam-webster)

Additionally it is more conventionally used in a negative context. E.g.:

> This is not my métier.

Furtheremore I neither know how common it actually is.

*Subject*, as suggested in the earlier answer, would work as well.

Comment: "Métier" is not common in English.  An ngram comparing your three terms (all meanings) is [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=m%C3%A9tier%2Cscope%2Cfield&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cm%C3%A9tier%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bm%C3%A9tier%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BM%C3%A9tier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cscope%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bscope%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BScope%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSCOPE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cfield%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfield%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BField%3B%2Cc0).